# What do I need to do to get my microphone detected?

Tags: python, pycharm, speech-recognition, microphone

I tired to make a simple "voice to text" program in python. It's not a difficult task as I see, but my code doesn't work. I don't get any error or warning messages, the program doesn't detect my voice in PyCharm. I checked my microphone, and it's working.

My code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

Comment: What OS is this on? Have you ensured that your default audio input device is the microphone you're using? Have you verified that other programs can pick up clear audio, at a decent volume, from the microphone?

Comment: I tested the microphone on two different platforms and the sound was perfect. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: So the microphone itself works, that's good, although you didn't answer all my questions; have you made sure it's the default audio device on the system you're running the script on?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, this is the default audio device on my system.